# Which test I should use to analyze the data from a Likert survey?

Tags: anova, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I'm now analyzing my data but it has frustrated me a lot! I have no idea what test I need to use.

I'm going to do an experiment about second language acquisition, before that I have to evaluate my stimuli. In the stimuli, 36 verbs were used to write sentences with four conditions: grammatical-finite, grammatical-nonfinite, ungrammatical-finite, ungrammatical-nonfinite. So there are 36*4=144 sentences altogether.

The survey is an online 7-point Likert one (1 for ungrammatical and 7 for grammatical) and each participant read 18 from all the 144 sentences totally randomly. The participants were asked to rate these sentences according to grammaticality. In the end, each sentence has got 33 responses.

The result looks like this:
[image]

I'd like to know what test I need to use to analyze them. I need to find out the sentences which are distinct from the others. For example, I want to know if, within all the verbs, the other two variables (grammaticality and finiteness) have the same main effects or interactions with the rest.

Statistics really drives me crazy!

Comment: If you're willing to assume Likert data are approximately normal, you could view this as a three-way ANOVA. Factors: G (gram vs non), F (finite vs non), V (36 levels), with 33 replications (Likert responses) in each of the $2 \times 2 \times 36$ cells. Then test G (I guess signif), F (I guess not signif), and V (can't guess). Also test for interactions GxF, GxV, FxV. // Not sure what "verb stands out" means. Maybe just look at cell totals down each column to see if there are high or low outliers. // If not assuming Likert approx norm, then start w/ Friedman test on 4 factors & verbs as blocks.